# How to access obained linear equations solution in SymPy?

Tags: python, sympy

I solved some system of linear equations using sympy as:

```
t=linsolve([f(0.25), f(0.5)], (a1,a2)) #f is function of x, a1, a2

Output: t={(-0.145903479236813, -0.152637485970819)}
```

How to access value of a1 and a2 from t?

Comment: Please include a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In particular, you need to include your definitions of f, a1, and a2 for someone to reproduce your result.

Answer (score 2):

`t` is a `set` (well, a `FiniteSet` according to the [docs](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solveset.html#sympy.solvers.solveset.linsolve)) of `tuple`s, being each `tuple` a solution, so you need to iterate over its solutions. Something like:

```
for a1, a2 in t:
    print(a1, a2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the elements of the solution set by converting it to `tuple` or `list`.

```
t=list(t)[0]
t[0]:-0.145903479236813
t[1]:-0.152637485970819
```